# Extract Original Markups tags as annotation Set in Gate NLP

Tags: gate

I am trying to extract html li tag,as shown in image below, as AnnotationSet and use it up for further processing in java. Is it possible to do so?
[image]

Comment: Possible for sure, see the documentation for GATE embedded - the java API of GATE https://gate.ac.uk/family/embedded.html
Not sure weather you need more info or not ...?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AnnotationSet Transfer PR can help you to copy annotations from "Original markups" to default set.